# invalid FormalParameterList, Syntax error on token ".", { expected after this token

Tags: java

How to fix this statement?

```
System.out.printf("    1     |    %d     |   %d |   %d\n" , 
                    Simulator.simulate(2, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200), 
                    Simulator.simulate(5, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200), 
                    Simulator.simulate(10, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200)      
                  );
```

---

```
Syntax error on token ".", { expected after this token [. in Simulator.simulate]

Syntax error on token ""    1     |    %d     |   %d |   %d\n"", invalid FormalParameterList
```

Comment: Compile time error? The cause of this may be outside of this statement. Maybe you missed a `{` or `}` somewhere.

Comment: You have a syntax error somewhere else, there's nothing wrong with that particular line as that is how you call `printf()`

Comment: Double check that the statement is (1) inside a method, (2) inside a constructor or (3) in a static initializer. Similiar errors signal that some statement is written outside a method...

Comment: It's inside public class Analyzer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates exactly the same error (and some more)

```
public class Analyzer {
   System.out.printf("    1     |    %d     |   %d |   %d\n" , 
                Simulator.simulate(2, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200), 
                Simulator.simulate(5, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200), 
                Simulator.simulate(10, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200)      
              );
}
```

The method call `System.out.printf` is **not allowed** in the class body. Move it in a method, a constructor or a static initializer:

```
public class Analyzer {
   static {
     System.out.printf("    1     |    %d     |   %d |   %d\n" , 
                Simulator.simulate(2, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200), 
                Simulator.simulate(5, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200), 
                Simulator.simulate(10, 1, 0.71, 15, 1200)      
              );
   }
}
```